# JQuery sortable table plugin not working with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) to create tabs on a webpage which works fine.  Within each of these tabs I want to have one of [these](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) sortable tables.  The table works properly in the first tab but the tables in all of the other tabs appear but cannot be sorted.  Does anyone have any idea why the functionality does not carry over to the other tabs?

This is the code that I have for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Results</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {      
            $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});
            $("#options").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]], headers: { 3:{sorter: false}, 4:{sorter: false}}});
        }); 
    </script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jq.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/results.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main"> 

    <a href="../index.html"><< Return to Home Page</a>

    <a name="Results"></a>
    <h1>Results</h1>

    <div class="container bs-docs-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9" role="main">

                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
                    <li class><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
                    <li class><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="1">
                        <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="header">Name</th>
                                    <th class="header headerSortDown">Value 1</th>
                                    <th class="header">Value 2</th>
                                    <th class="header">Value 3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> 
                                <?php include('get_table_contents.php') ?>  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2">
                        <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="header">Name</th>
                                    <th class="header headerSortDown">Value 1</th>
                                    <th class="header">Value 2</th>
                                    <th class="header">Value 3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> 
                                <?php include('get_table_contents.php') ?>  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3">
                        <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="header">Name</th>
                                    <th class="header headerSortDown">Value 1</th>
                                    <th class="header">Value 2</th>
                                    <th class="header">Value 3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> 
                                <?php include('get_table_contents.php') ?>  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element IDs should be unique. In your code you have used the ID "tablesorter-demo" three times.

Use a unique ID for each tablesorter table element (e.g. "tablesorter-demo1", "tablesorter-demo2" etc.), and then make a call to "tablesorter()" for each one e.g.

```
$("#tablesorter-demo1").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});
$("#tablesorter-demo2").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});
```

Obviously change the input parameter for "tablesorter" if you want the tables to be different.

Also you dont have an element with the ID "options", so that is why that tablesorter is not being initialised.